# Adding SVG images from assets folder in adapter

Tags: android, svg, gridview

I want to load SVG in ImageView from Gridview Adapter,
i do this:

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/ico/s.svg"));
```

but not work and dont show anything

Answer (score 2):

> I want to load SVG in ImageView from Gridview Adapter, i do this:

First, `ImageView` does not support SVG directly.

Second, your code appears to be loading a PNG file, not an SVG file.

Third, `file:///android_asset/` is for `WebView`. It does not work elsewhere in the Android SDK.

You should consider switching to using Glide as an image-loader. It handles `file:///android_asset/` and has sample code for transcoding SVG files. Plus, it does the image-loading work on a background thread.

Otherwise, you can use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on an asset. If that asset is a PNG, JPEG, or WebP file, you can use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to read in the stream and give you a `Bitmap` back that you can use for the `ImageView`. You would need a third-party library to do something with an SVG asset. And, you need to arrange to do this work on a background thread, as otherwise your UI will freeze and cause users to think that your app is stuck.

Comment: if I convert my SVG to Android XML?

Comment: @ArMo372: I am not certain what you mean by that. If you mean using the Vector Asset wizard in Android Studio to create vector drawable XML, I have never tried loading that from an asset. It certainly works as a `drawable` resource.